# Simplifying $\scriptsize\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}} + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}} + \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, radicals

The question is in the title: is there a simpler form or result for

$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}} + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}} + \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}\quad?$$

Comment: The expressions for $\cos\left(\dfrac\pi{2^n}\right)$ and $\sin\left(\dfrac\pi{2^n}\right)$ come in handy here, I'll bet. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%28pi%2F2%5E6%29%2C+sin%28pi%2F2%5E6%29

Comment: The tag ([tag:roots]) is for zeroes of functions, the tags ([tag:arithmetic]) and ([tag:radicals]) are better tags for questions about square roots, cube roots, etc. From [roots tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/roots/info): For questions about "square roots", "cube roots", and such, consider using the (radicals) and (arithmetic) tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$ \cos 2\theta =2\cos ^2\theta -1\Rightarrow \cos\theta=\sqrt{\dfrac{\cos 2\theta+1}{2}} $

Therefore $$\cos \dfrac{\pi}{8}=\sqrt{\dfrac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+1}{2}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{2}}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2}.$$

Hence $$\cos \dfrac{\pi}{16}=\sqrt{\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2}+1}{2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}{2}.$$

Then $$\cos \dfrac{\pi}{32}=\sqrt{\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}{2}+1}{2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}}{2}.$$

Since $\sin^2 \dfrac{\pi}{32}+\cos^2 \dfrac{\pi}{32}=1$ we have $$\sin \dfrac{\pi}{32}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}}{2}.$$

So $$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}} + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}} + \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}\\
=2\left(\cos \dfrac{\pi}{8}+\cos \dfrac{\pi}{16}+\cos \dfrac{\pi}{32}+\sin \dfrac{\pi}{32}\right)\dots$$

Comment: yeah... but is it possible to simplify more from here?